# Adding a high risk bet to a portfolio of lower risk bets

Tags: probability

I have a portfolio of 15 independent lower risk bets with  60% chance of $4 return on $1 bet and 40% chance of total loss. I want to add bet 16 which is a much higher risk bet - 20% chance of $25 return and 80% chance of total loss. I want to make  4 more bets but want to minimize the standard deviation of the resulting portfolio. Am I better off adding 4 similar high risk bets or 4 of the low risk bets or is it the same either way?
Another option is to split Bet 16 into 5 20cent bets and then proceed with normal risk bets. Which of these options minimize SD?

Comment: You have not given us enough information to answer, but in general $\text{Var}(w'R)  = w'\Sigma w$ where $R$ are the returns, $w$ are the weights that you choose, and $\Sigma$ is the variance-covariance matrix of $R$. You can fiddle with $w$ and see what happens to the square root of this, or you can use mean-variance optimization methods to get answer, assuming you know $\Sigma$ and $\mu$ (the expectation of $R$) (which you probably don't).

Comment: This depends very strongly on how the "bets" are related and how you are measuring "risk". As stated the question cannot be answered.

Comment: All bets are independent and the low risk bets have a 60% chance of $4 return on $1 bet and 40% chance of loss. Bet 16 has a 20% chance of $25 and 80% chance of loss. To minimize SD would I do 4 more risky bets to complete the portfolio or 4 safer bets or would they be the same. Sorry if this is still not enough info but I am trying to get at this question - does just one high risk bet create the most volatile returns and 5 of them give you a better chance of achieving that high return and thus less variance.

Comment: @RickDefieux can you edit your original question and provide this information up there?

Comment: I am trying to understand - if you are funding very low probability endeavors with a very high payout it does not make sense unless you fund enough of them to have a decent chance to succeed. So why does this not apply to the situation of adding high risk projects to a low risk portfolio? All projects are independent. 15 projects exist with a 60% chance of a 4x payout and 40% chance of zero. Number 16 (of 20 $1 bets) has a 20% chance of a $25 payout. If a goal is to minimize variance, should i do just one of these and the final 4 as the usual bets or is it better to do more high risk bets?